# Subsets and permutations

Tags: probability

120 pianists compete in a piano competition.

(a)
In the first round, 30 of the 120 are selected to go on to the next round. How many different outcomes are there for the first round?

(b)
In the second round, the judges select the first, second, third, fourth and fifth place winners of the competition from among the 30 pianists who advanced to the second round. How many outcomes are there for the second round of the competition?

For the question (b), people are telling me the order does not matter but I am sure it does since there is a ranking; so it should be P(30,5).

What is your opinion?

thanks

Comment: What did you come up with for (a)?  If you understand that, part (b) is easier.

Comment: You are correct.  Since the winners are ranked, part (b) is a permutation question.

Comment: thanks, for (a) i have 120 choose 30

Comment: That's correct.  Part (a) is unordered samples without repetition, while part (b) is ordered samples without repetition.